# Why isnt my laptop connecting to my external monitor?

Tags: laptop, windows-10, multiple-monitors, hdmi, dvi

Alienware M17X-R3
Windows 10 (this might be the problem...)
DVI-D cable
HDMI to DVI adapter
ACER external monitor model no. G236HL

For some reason, my laptop won't display anything on the external. Might I need specific drivers for this to work? Dell support suggested that it might be a problem with my external monitor, but if anyone has any ideas that would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Super User. First and foremost, did you see the warning on the [Dell Support page](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/product-support/product/alienware-m17x-r3/drivers) for this model? *"Dell is not testing or developing Windows 10 drivers for this product. If you choose to upgrade, some features, applications, and connected devices may not work as expected."* Other than that, did this work before upgrading to Windows 10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would personally have to look at it, but try to update your video card driver's. Also try, right click on desktop --> go to screen resolution --> click identify and see if the second monitor comes up. If not it may be a monitor or cable problem, if it does show up, than it's most likely a driver/software problem.

Comment: Definitely a software/driver problem. Everything else seems fine.

Comment: Ok, find out if the grapics card driver is correct and up-to-dat. If so I would assume that its was what @CharlieRB said, just a dell thing.

Comment: Ok so it says I have the latest version of my Intel graphics driver, now Im going to check GeForce for the latest version of NVIDIA. Is it weird that I have 2? It's a gaming laptop

Comment: 2 drivers? Like a HD graphics and geforce? If you have two cards than no its not weird. Have you tried enabling multi-boot in your bios?

Comment: I'm not sure about the 2 physical cards...actually, it wouldn't make sense to have 1 card with 2 different kinds of drivers from 2 diff companies. And if by "multi-boot" you mean that if I've partitioned my hard drive to be able to run 2 kinds of OS's, then no.

Comment: No, if you go into your bios and look at video(?) setting. There is a multi-display option. It allows you to use you integrated graphics card (Intel HD Graphics) and an addition graphics card (Your Geforce card) at the same time. As for the 2 drivers situation, if you have 2 graphics devices. You'll have two drivers.